# Consulta: ¿Bootstrap 4 tooltip en option select?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap, html-select

Buen día para saber si alguien ha podido generar tooltips en un `option select` usando bootstrap 4: mi código es el siguiente

**HTML**:

```js
    <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
      $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
     });
    </script>
```

```html
    <select class="form-control" name="idObjetivo" id="idObjetivo">
  <option value="valor" data-toggle="tooltip" title="titulo">
   Texto Opción
  </option>
 </select>
```

Pero cuando paso sobre las opciones no se ve el title, solo se ve cuando quieto el atributo 'data-toggle="tooltip"' de las option y quiero que tenga el estilo de los tooltip de bootstrap 4, Muchas gracias

Comment: Primeramente te falta cerrar el </script>

Comment: En el código lo tengo cerrado, se me fue al copiar el código aca, muchas gracias

Comment: Entonces cual es el problema?, probando desde aqui el tooltip aparece en la primera opcion del select.

Comment: Que no muestra el tooltip en cada option select cuando se usa la el atributo ' data-toggle="tooltip"'

Answer (score -1):

Te faltan Clases amigo además del data-toggle igual chececha con ello y mandalo a llamar en tu script data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Tooltip on left"
Igual checa el uso de data-toggle. Saludos.

[introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/tooltips/)